# Speed up jQueryUI button

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a webpage with a lot of checkboxes that I turn into pushbuttons with jQueryUI button() call. This slows the rendering of the page down to a crawl. Is it possible to speed this up?

I do the call in `document.ready` with selector

```
$("#containingdiv input[type='checkbox']).button()
```

I am building a control for a bracket cup. And i am showing the brackts for all agegroups, that is the reason for so many checkboxes. The ones marked in red boxes ar checkboxes and the other ones is normal buttons. There are up to 30 agegroups so i need to show alot of them.

[image]

Looks like i should build the ui myself instead of using the pushbuttons from jqueryui. When i profile i chrome it looks like it is building all the nodes that uses all the time.

Comment: You might see the suggestion by ChaosPandion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883611/should-i-use-jquery-each

Comment: 1000-2000 depends on what info i am showing.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a great UX. Maybe consider pagination.

Comment: Storing the returnvalue from lookup of all boxes did not give me any speedup, looks like building and inserting the nodes for the fancy buttons in the dom uses most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following trick. Instead of converting them all at once, convert first hundred (or how many user immidiately sees on the screen), and delay the rest with `setTimeout()`. This releases the UI thread almost immidiately, therefore browser can do other things like rendering and processing events. Initialization actually becomes longer, but the page is never frozen.

Something like:

```js
var checkboxes_left = $("#containingdiv input[type='checkbox']");
convertRest();

// Convert the first 100 checkboxes, then schedule converting the rest
function convertRest() {
    checkboxes_left.slice(0, 100).button();
    checkboxes_left = checkboxes_left.slice(100);
    if (checkboxes_left.length > 0) {
        window.setTimeout(convertRest, 50);
    }
}
```